# loading the package ggh4x in error: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggh4x’: object ‘cli_abort’ is not exported by 'namespace:cli'

Tags: r, macos, package, command-line-interface

whilst loading the ggh4 package in R version 2022.07.1.
I get the following error.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggh4x’:
object ‘cli_abort’ is not exported by 'namespace:cli'

What I tried:

Removing the ggh4 package and downloading it from github:

devtools::install_github("teunbrand/ggh4x")

Removing the cli package and downloading it from github:

devtools::install_github("teunbrand/ggh4x")

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: install.packages('ggh4x')
library(ggh4x)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, you need to install the `cli` package first ! :)